# Binding Button.text property in the event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to work on Xamarin tutorial which I need to create a button and when I click it, it changes it text.
Here is my XAML code:

```
<ViewCell>
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
   <Image Source="{Binding ImageURl}"></Image>
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
       <Label x:Name="ContactName" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
       <Label Text="{Binding Status}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
   </StackLayout>
   <Button x:Name="mybtn" Text="Follow" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Here is my Code-Behind C#

```
public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mybtn.text = "Following";
        }
```

Every time I write this `mybtn.text= "following"`, the log says `Error   CS0103  The name 'mybtn' does not exist in the current context  MobileApp`

Can someone tell me where I go wrong? is this how the bind elements should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't refer to elements by name when they are contained in templates

instead, do this

```
public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        button.text = "Following";
    }
```